# Computational Verification of conjecture on Cunningham Chains

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

A Cunningham Chain is defined as a sequence of prime numbers $p_i$ such that $p_{i+1} = 2p_i +1$ (or $p_k = 2^k (p_0 + 1) - 1$). The conjecture is that there infinitely many Cunningham Chains of any given length $k$. One way this conjecture could be false, is if there exist positive integer $N$ such that for every $1≤n<N$, there exist a $k$ such that $mod(2^k(n+1) -1, N)$ is a non-trivial factor of $N$. My question is can anyone disprove existence of such $N$? If one cannot disprove the existence of such $N$, can anyone derive a lower bound to value of such $N$?

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0025570X.2020.1704613

Comment: Of first kind* the hard part would be 9 mod 10

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  why would it be the hard part tho?

Comment: It's the only remainder mod 10 that can produce lengths greater than 4

Comment: Same with being 5 mod 6 ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  oh no i realized that (-1 mod N) is always guaranteed to "survive" lmao. Meaning my question is pointless

Comment: It has a point. It's called a lesson learning experience.

Comment: Mine is to read the question. Been out of focus lately.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  ok thanks!!